# How to draw a commutative diagram

Tags: commutative-diagrams

I want to write a code for the following diagram in TeX, may you please help me how I can write that:[image]

Comment: Tip: on this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I put text above and below an arrow in tikzcd") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this diagram?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Next time, try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll not always get someone willing to do it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite easy using `tikz-cd`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=2cm,row sep=2cm]
  \textbf{As}
  \arrow[r,"\bot","\text{Lie}_\text{as}"',yshift=-1ex]
  \arrow[d,"\dashv"',"\subset",xshift=1ex]
  &
  \textbf{Lie}
  \arrow[l,"U"',yshift=1ex]
  \arrow[d,"\vdash","\subset"',xshift=-1ex]
  \\
  \textbf{Dias}
  \arrow[r,"Lb","\top"',yshift=1ex]
  \arrow[u,"As",xshift=-1ex]
  &
  \textbf{Lb}
  \arrow[u,"\text{Lie}_\text{Lb}"',xshift=1ex]
  \arrow[l,"U_d",yshift=-1ex]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```